# Microsoft Exchange 2010 Email Format

Tags: email, networking, exchange-server

My Company using Exchange server 2010 , after  upgrades  some users have problem with email format, If the users send something to other one , they recieved it has  with  Plaing text and it contain the HTML tags.

How I  solve this in Exchange 2010.

Please check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you have not crate new profile since you have upgraded those users , If that is the case check this link out

[create profile](http://www.emailsignature.eu/phpBB2/how-to-create-and-verify-a-new-outlook-profile-t768.html)

otherwise you will need to trouble shoot  your HTML and Exchange  Sever 2003 Note! HTML emails from Outlook 2010 (and 2007) renders perfectly across all major email clients.
 If you use HTML coding that is generally supported in email clients, your Outlook 2010 emails will also look the same in your recipients inboxes. also Often issues are caused by CSS which is generally not supported.